# Strip brackets from String after list.toString operation

Tags: java, list, tostring

Does anyone know how to strip the brackets off the ends of a resulting string after running a List.toString() operation. Im wondering if there is a build in operation. One that does not involve looping through the string or creating a sub-string of the second and list.size()-1. Some code below. Thanks!

```
 List<Element> elementsBetween = new ArrayList<Element>();
 elementBetween.add("some data");
 String result = = elementsBetween.toString();
```

Comment: I would personally just create the substring.

Comment: Using the `toString` method of the `List` in your program logic is **fundamentally flawed**. If you want to create some special representation either extend `ArrayList` and add a method to do so of create a utility method. **Do not** rely on the `toString` representation remaining constant.

Comment: What's wrong with the sub-string option? That's the simplest and cleanest way to do it...

Comment: Do it yourself instead or use `StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(elementsBetween.toString()).deleteCharAt(0); sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length()-1); sb.toString();`

Comment: Yeh is suppose the sub-string option is fine. Im just surprised the toString method does'nt provide a way to strip the brackets off automatically.  @Luiggi your method looks good i might use that. Boris im not sure i know what you mean. Im using a html parser to add tags to a list and then flush them to a string. Sorry i just provided a short code snippet above. are there better ways to do it?

Comment: @BoristheSpider I wouldn't even accept subclassing `ArrayList` because the code is most likely programmed to the `List` interface, so any other implementation can slip in and ruin the logic. I say just *don't* use `toString` for business logic, period.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I was more thinking about adding a different method to the sublass such as `toCsv` and coding against the subclass. A statically imported utility method would be somewhat neater...

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik what would be an better solution? What im actually trying to do is pass html tags into a list and then to a string to for display in an android TextView..

Comment: I would write a separate utility method to deal with this, not an instance method of the list. Look at the answers, they both suggest using some ready-made utility functions; you can write your own as well (I'd do that :)

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understand you you want a List of String elements to be represented as:

```
 "element1, element2, element3"
```

You should use a library like apache commons-lang. E.g. the [StringUtils.join(Collection collection, String separator)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#join%28java.util.Collection,%20java.lang.String%29)

```
 List<Element> elementsBetween = new ArrayList<Element>();
 elementBetween.add("some data1");
 elementBetween.add("some data2");
 String joined = StringUtils.join(elementsBetween, ", ");
 // joined will be equal to
 "some data1, some data2"
```

Answer (score 3):

Using [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/), you can do:

```
List<String> items = Arrays.asList("a","b","c");
String output = Joiner.on(", ").join(items);
System.out.println(output);
```

which will result in:

```
a, b, c
```

You can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122517/displaying-list-in-java-as-elegant-as-in-python).